# Unknown component analytics:reportChart error in Eclipse IDE

Tags: visualforce, ide, analytics

I have a strange issue in eclipse IDE .Here is my vf code

```
<apex:page >
<div style="width:485px;margin:auto;">
        <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O28000001mWil" />              
   </div>
```

This code is saved successfully when I save it online from my dev org, but the same fails when I have save it from my eclipse force.com IDE. Showing the same error as shown in heading.I have used 29.0 api version for my page. Please guide !
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What version of Eclipse?

Comment: eclipse version :  3.8.2

Comment: I use Mavensmate, but experience this type of situation semi-frequently. If you toggle between compiling using the Tooling API and Metadata API, that solves it in MM.

Comment: Thanks ! But what about eclipse :|

Answer (score 1):

I edited api version of my page to 33.0 and this problem got solved !

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Monalisa it may be interesting to extend your answer as to why this resolved the issue. I'm assuming the Analytics VF component wasn't available yet in the 29.0 API version.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke if this this component wasn't available in api 29.0 version then how come I am able to save the same code online in my org. This probably suggest that the problem basically persist in eclipse!

Comment: @Guy .Yes you are right it is not the answer to the given question.But since it solves the issue it probably suggest the pitfalls that exist in this force.com IDE!And sorry I dint got you !where I need to comment for clarification from author